# Laravel queue retries delay

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, queue, beanstalkd

I am building a large application using Laravel and find the use of queue in this application. I am now using beanstalkd service for this. However, I am stuck in finding an answer for this set up. Is there a way to put the queue retries be processed in not instantly manner. I wanted it to be retried after n seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the inbuilt `Queue` service and use the following

```
Queue::later(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1), $task);
```

[Relevant docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues)

Comment: Is this possible to implement this for retries? @scopey

Comment: It might be possible to hook into the `failing` hook and do a custom retry. Additionally, setting the `--delay` flag on your queue worker gives an ambiguous delay. Not entirely sure that there's a set way to delay specific retries otherwise.

Comment: I just try sending out emails (and expecting them to fail) using the two following commands on Laravel 4.2: `php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3 --sleep=60` versus `php artisan queue:work --daemon --tries=3 --sleep=5 --delay=10` and I can confirm that using the second command, the retries were attempted after a 10 seconds delay instead of being retried immediately (which was the case when I used the first command).

Answer (score 2):

In the **queue:work** command **--delay** option is deprecated.

You have to use **--backoff**

```
--backoff[=BACKOFF]    The number of seconds to wait before retrying a job that encountered an uncaught exception [default: "0"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To delay the next retry just add `--delay=[NUM_OF_SECONDS]` to your command.

For example, to wait 30 seconds to retry after failing just run: `php artisan queue:work tries=3 --delay=30`